# Qt recursive singleshot timer seems to cause memory leak

Tags: c++, qt, timing

I have a function in C++/Qt that calls recursively with a singleshot timer. By my understanding, a singleshot timer should timeout once and doesn't require any memory cleanup. I've narrowed the memory leak down to just one line of code. It causes the program to slowly but steadily use more RAM over time. I let it run for two hours and it got to 2.2 GB from about 50 MB starting out. As a minimal example, I have this:

```
void executionLoop() {
    QTimer::singleShot(1, Qt::PreciseTimer, this, SLOT(executionLoop()));
}
```

So if this is working like I think it should, executionLoop should run, set a singleshot timer, let Qt do whatever, and then callback after 1 millisecond, set another singleshot and repeat until the program is stopped. Somehow, the program just continues to eat RAM just from this one line. If I do something like:

```
while (0 == 0)
{
    QCoreApplication::processevents();
    executionLoop();
}
```

with executionLoop being an empty function, there is still a memory leak, but it grows exponentially faster. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: But how? I can have the timer set to more than 10 milliseconds and it still happens. Surely, that'd be enough time for Qt to process any routine events. Also, I wouldn't be generating any events with the endless while loop.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with a simple example (Suse Linux + Qt5.15.2).  Please provide a [mcve] and details of your OS, Qt version etc.  Also give details of how you are measuring memory usage.

Comment: This is on a Windows 7 machine with Qt 6.0.0. I created a fresh widget project and made the function above as a slot exactly like I posted except for the MainWindow class name. I called executionLoop from the MainWindow constructor and got the same behavior. It's slow, but it does eventually use more and more RAM without ever seeming to free any. Just to be clear, I'm only calling executionLoop once from outside and recursively with the timer. I'm not using the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
step 1:
main calls executionloop which schedules timerA
step 2:
main calls executionloop which schedules timerB
timerA calls executionloop which schedules timerC
step 3:
main calls executionloop which schedules timerD
timerB calls executionloop which schedules timerE
timerC calls executionloop which schedules timerF
step 4:
...
```

Comment: This shouldn't happen though. The point of a singleshot timer in Qt is that it only triggers once. The existing timer should be destroyed each time executionLoop is called. Also, executionLoop is only called once from outside. It calls itself after that.

Comment: I mean that each time executionLoop is called, there shouldn't be a timer to call it again until the singleshot statement is executed. There should never be more than one timer set to call executionLoop at any given point.

Comment: The while loop doesn't create a timer at all. That was only another example that causes a memory leak. It calls executionLoop repeatedly and executionLoop is an empty function. The scenario in the answer couldn't possibly exist in that case. If you read my first comment again, you'll see that I said executionLoop is only called once from outside of itself.

Comment: In my answer every timer has a unique name and fires only once. I'm pretty sure calling singleshot doesn't destroy existing singleshot calls that haven't yet triggered. That would be a nightmare in large applications that called it from more than one place.

Comment: No, I mean that only one singleshot will be enabled at any given time because the singleshot is only created in the function and the function is only called by the singleshot after the first time. Anyway, I reported this on Qt's forums and others reproduced it, so it seems like a genuine bug in Qt 6.0.0 and up.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer. This was confirmed as a bug in Windows Qt 6.0.0 and later. It is apparently not present in older versions. The bug is being tracked here if anyone is interested: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-92912